# Error - NSTask with top command

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm using `top -l 1` to get required information.

When I try to launch the above command using `NSTask` I'm getting error saying that `launch path not accessible`

Here the code:

```
let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/bin/top"
task.arguments = ["-l","1"]
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()
```

Is the given launch path correct?

Thank you!

---

**Edit:**

using `task.lauchPath = "/usr/bin/top"` worked but when I enable sandbox there's an error - `Couldn't posix_spawn: error 1`

Is it possible to use `top` when the app is sandboxed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Terminal app, and enter `which top`.

```
OOPers-MacBook:~ dev$ which top
/usr/bin/top
```

Try with `task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/top"`.

Comment: It's working but if I enable sandbox there's an error - `Couldn't posix_spawn: error 1`. Can't I use `top` when sandbox is enabled?

Comment: @user6528991, most likely no. Sandboxed apps cannot call arbitrary binaries.

Comment: but I can use `system_profiler` without any problem

Comment: @user6528991, I haven't checked all available binaries, but the actual result for `top` is what you see. Some other might be able to tell you how to use `top` in sandboxed app, but I don't have any clue about it.

Comment: @OOPer `top` is setuid root, which means you can't use it from the sandbox.

Comment: @tbodt, thanks for clarifying. seems I need to learn much more in this region.